# Python closes child windows when program is rerun

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot where one of the commands you can tell it is to start a Minecraft server in the form of a command prompt via this code.

`os.startfile(f'C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/Minecraft Servers/{server}/run.bat')`

Everything works fine the only problem is when I rerun the code(For example to add a new feature) all the command prompt windows are closed. Is there a way to stop this link between python and the command prompt? I am using pycharm with python 3.8.1 if that matters

Comment: you can try to run it in separated thread with `daemon = True` but I don't know if it works on Windows. [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) But it can make other problem - you will no have access to this thread and you can't stop it, and if you run again thread then you will have two servers running.

Comment: @furas where do I put `daemon = True`